# Vcc and gnd in microcontroller on proteus

Tags: power, 5v, proteus

The microcontroller power pins (Vcc,gnd) in the proteus are set to 5 volts by default. I have basic regulator circuit (my vcc 3.3 volt). How can I use my circuit for microcontroller power supply?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the nets where hidden pins are connected.

Please refer to this: [How to unhide hidden pins in proteus?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191336/how-to-unhide-hidden-pins-in-proteus)

Comment: Thanks for comment,but,in this topic images links are broken down.So,i don't understand.Also,I am using proteus 8.And,i didn't find terminals menu.Can you help me?

Comment: I have succeed unhide the hide pins in microcontroller.But,even if I connect the voltage source to these pins, the default VCC value does not change.Can you help me?

Comment: @johny9a, in the "Design" menu, look for "Configure Power Rails". This is where you can change the Vcc voltage, and also create other power rails, with other voltages. You just create/edit each power rail, and then choose which power nets are connected to each power rail. Remember that to create a proper power net, you have to use the Terminals mode, and create a Power terminal, otherwise it won't show in the "Configure Power Rails" menu.