# Force Proteus to unhide hidden pins

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus

This can be categorized as duplicate question with question in the link below, BUT the reason I ask this because the answer in that question DOESN'T ANSWER the question on how to unhide hidden pins in proteus. The answer in that question only shows a workaround, not the real answer to the question.

[How to unhide hidden pins in proteus?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191336/how-to-unhide-hidden-pins-in-proteus)

Let's get into it. **How to force proteus to show hidden pins**, so it doesn't require me to create external switch in real life outside proteus which quite messy, or so I don't need to detach my battery just to TURN OFF microprocessor with hidden pins such as ATMEGA8535 and ect which always connect to the power source.

If it require me to copy and modify the model of ATMEGA8535 in Proteus and edit it so it will show hidden pin, and import it back to proteus. How do I do it?

Or maybe there is actually already exist a way to do this? I'm a beginner and please don't say

> "It's easy just do this and that and you done "

Step-by-step please.

Comment: It seems like they *do* answer your question. According to the second answer the hidden pins are a feature of the library part, so you need to make your own custom part with them not hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the schematic symbol for that.

In the properties of the pin, simply tick the "Draw Body" checkbutton, if I rememeber correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the component on the schematic, you need to right-click it and click "*Decompose*". If it is a simulated model, you will see a lot of text underneath it. **Do not delete or edit the text or the component will not simulate after**. The hidden pins will now be shown. Just double click them and click the "*Draw body*" option. You can move the pins to a more appropriate place, and type in the pin name to be shown too. Then highlight the component **and** the text and click "*Make device*". Then type in the appropriate information for the components and click "*Next*" to move on. For a component that already exists, all the information should be there, so just check there is nothing you want to change, and just click "*Next*" when happy.

At the end it will ask if you want to update all instances of device, and just click "*OK*". This will update the component in the library. You can now use the part as you did before, with the hidden pins shown.